# Парсинг с помощью Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php

Есть код

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function get_result($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    return $res;
}

function parser_simple_html($url, $i) {
    if($i < 2) {
        $html = str_get_html(get_result($url));
        $blog = $html->find('div[id=dle-content]', 0);
        foreach($blog->find('.movie-item') as $root) {
            $courses = $root->find('.movie-title', 0)->href;
            $vse = $courses;
            print $vse."<br>";

        }

        if (isset($blog->find('.navigation', 0)->next_sibling()->find('a', 0)->href) && !empty($blog->find('.navigation', 0)->next_sibling()->find('a', 0)->href));
            $href = $blog->find('.navigation', 0)->next_sibling()->find('a', 0)->href;
            $i++;
            parser_simple_html($href,$i);
    }


}
$i = 0;
parser_simple_html('https://uakino.club/film/',$i);
```

Который забирает все ссылки на фильмы

Как теперь мне пройтись по всем этим ссылкам?

Comment: Сделать return из функции и сохранить в переменную.

Comment: Не подскажите как?

Comment: Я ведь выше уже написал. Из функции `parser_simple_html` вернуть данные, и при вызове этой функции записать данные в переменную

Comment: Ну, раз получилось выбрать ссылки и напечатать на странице, должно получиться их там же и в массив сложить! А потом можете пройтись хоть циклом, хоть ногами